# Генерация ячеек таблицы jquery

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте у меня вопрос. У меня есть таблица 
и такой html код

```
<table class="simple-little-table" cellspacing='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name </th>
                        <th>Diploma</th>
                        <th>Qualification</th>
                        <th>Accept or Reject</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="name">John</td>
                        <td class="seeDiploma">see diploma</td>
                        <td>biology</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="acept">Accept</div>
                            <div class="reject">Reject</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Мне нужно написать код который бы генерировал ячейки таблицы name, seeDiploma, biology, acept, reject. Вообщем все что под шапкой таблицы генерировалось динамически из определенной базы данных. Спасибо за любую помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавление элементов в JQuery можно выполнить с помощью функций [`.append(target)`](https://jquery-docs.ru/append/), [`.prepend(target)`](https://jquery-docs.ru/prepend/), [`.appendTo(target)`](https://jquery-docs.ru/appendTo/) или [`.prependTo(target)`](https://jquery-docs.ru/prependTo/), где target - элемент в который вставляются элементы. Почитай документацию [JQuery](https://jquery-docs.ru/) там ничего сложного нет. А так для рендера подобных конструкций лучше использовать React.js.